openCV gray scale video missing right half
i'm trying to save a video using openCV with mitigated success. My (simplified) code is pretty basic:
const cv::Mat imgDisplay16( mHeight, mWidth, CV_16U, aImage.data() );
mWriter              = std::make_unique<cv::VideoWriter>( "file.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc( 'M', 'J', 'P', 'G' ), 10, imgDisplay16.size(), false );
mWriter->write( imgDisplay16 );
//cv::imwrite( "path.png", imgDisplay16 );

The problem is that the resulting video is missing the right half of the image, see captures below. The image is also really ugly, but thats another problem.
Im just starting with openCV so it may be a basic error.
Thanks
Problematic video:

Expected output:

if it can be useful, there is this in my log
[ INFO:0@4.737] global videoio_registry.cpp:244 cv::`anonymous-namespace'::VideoBackendRegistry::VideoBackendRegistry VIDEOIO: Enabled backends(9, sorted by priority): FFMPEG(1000); GSTREAMER(990); INTEL_MFX(980); MSMF(970); DSHOW(960); CV_IMAGES(950); CV_MJPEG(940); UEYE(930); OBSENSOR(920)
[ INFO:0@4.737] global backend_plugin.cpp:383 cv::impl::getPluginCandidates Found 3 plugin(s) for FFMPEG
[ INFO:0@4.737] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Git\ino_cameraapi\out\build\x64-Debug\bin\opencv_videoio_ffmpeg481_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@4.738] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_ffmpeg481_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0@4.741] global plugin_loader.impl.hpp:67 cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_videoio_ffmpeg481_64.dll => OK
[ INFO:0@4.741] global backend_plugin.cpp:50 cv::impl::PluginBackend::initCaptureAPI Found entry: 'opencv_videoio_capture_plugin_init_v1'
[ INFO:0@4.741] global backend_plugin.cpp:169 cv::impl::PluginBackend::checkCompatibility Video I/O: initialized 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Capture plugin': built with OpenCV 4.8 (ABI/API = 1/1), current OpenCV version is '4.8.1' (ABI/API = 1/1)
[ INFO:0@4.741] global backend_plugin.cpp:69 cv::impl::PluginBackend::initCaptureAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to use 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Capture plugin'
[ INFO:0@4.741] global backend_plugin.cpp:84 cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Found entry: 'opencv_videoio_writer_plugin_init_v1'
[ INFO:0@4.741] global backend_plugin.cpp:169 cv::impl::PluginBackend::checkCompatibility Video I/O: initialized 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Writer plugin': built with OpenCV 4.8 (ABI/API = 1/1), current OpenCV version is '4.8.1' (ABI/API = 1/1)
[ INFO:0@4.741] global backend_plugin.cpp:103 cv::impl::PluginBackend::initWriterAPI Video I/O: plugin is ready to use 'FFmpeg OpenCV Video I/O Writer plugin'

and i am in windows 10, openCV 4.8.1

That code example is pretty suspect -- you seem to construct the VideoWriter with isColor set to true, but then feed it a single channel image. That shouldn't work. You're also feeding it a 16 bit image, which is kinda odd for a video, and I'd say that's what's causing the image to be stretched (it's treating the MSB and LSB as separate pixels).

I see noise. I can't tell what's a "half" of the picture. did you notice that one of your pictures doesn't show "just" noise but some patterns? they look less than random.

@DanMašek indeed, the true was supposed to be a false, i copied/paste after running test. My input is a 16bit, should i convert it to CV_8U before feeding it to the video writer?

@ChristophRackwitz the second picture, is the same input, but with 'cv::imwrite( "path.png", imgDisplay16 );' and its the correct image. The "4"at the top is part of the image (its a sequence a 16 images with numbers on it)

you changed a vital part of the code (isColor) but did not update the screenshots. please make sure your question is consistent and reproducible ([mre]). if at all possible, try to mock/generate content in aImage so that we can too.

@ChristophRackwitz the screenshot were taken with isColor set to false. Your first comment was correct. Videowriter expect (I think) 8 bits data. Additional question, can I convert with imgDisplay16.convertTo( imgDisplay8, CV_8U, 1.0/256); or is there a better way (it works this way).
You can post an answer with the error about 16 bits and I should convert to 8 bits and I'll accept it. Else i will do it

VideoWriter expect 8bits data, so we need to convert the CV_16U image to a CV_8U image.
Working code is
const cv::Mat imgDisplay16( mHeight, mWidth, CV_16U, aImage.data() );
cv::Mat imgDisplay8;
imgDisplay16.convertTo( imgDisplay8, CV_8U, 1.0/256);
mWriter              = std::make_unique<cv::VideoWriter>( "file.avi", cv::VideoWriter::fourcc( 'M', 'J', 'P', 'G' ), 10, imgDisplay16.size(), false );
mWriter->write( imgDisplay8 );

